# How To get active vpn(site tot site) count from cisco FTD using ansible

Tags: cisco, firewall, automation, ansible

I have been trying to get active VPN count from FTD firewalls using ansible, I tried the same on ASA and it have been running successfully. But when comes to FTD ansible, As it uses httpapi instead of SSH, and I'm unable to find a proper documentation which tell us how to send commands over httpapi. I even tried it using traditional cli_command and cli_config. I later found out in ftd_configuration module we need to use command operation to send commands over to FTD. But still I'm unaware of the parameters for that module. So please comment your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the intro for the Cisco Secure Firewall API:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/firepower/ftd-api/guide/ftd-rest-api/ftd-rest-api-intro.html

I would recommend working with Cisco support to get more specific instruction on which API commands to use to retrieve the information you want. Their documentation on the API seems to be incomplete.

This page might be helpful on what areas to look for and names for API sections to browse through.

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/firepower/623/configuration/guide/fpmc-config-guide-v623/firepower_threat_defense_vpn_monitoring.html#id_48247

You can simply look at the API structure and contents in a browser by loading it from your firewall. That should allow you to look around and find data that helps you.

Comment: none of the above mentioned document, helps me as I already explored API option to gte active VPN sessions, as cisco doesn't have created an api in ftd check vpn sessions. So that's why I planned to get the data from ansible